# SQL Server agent not getting started

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-agent

I am trying to start my  sql server agent but it is not getting started . Showing the   following Error- `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I had made a scheduling a job.I tried to start the services from sql server configuration
but still it shows an error.I have try to start services from command prompt also but it is showing error-1067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a general windows error, not specific to sql server.
Check your windows log to get more info.

You can also try try to start SQL Agent  from command  with the -v switch to display the output to the diag screen.

Comment: an error message.i have an XP operating system in my machine.The same sql server R2 setup is installed in my laptop & in it Agent is working fine